# How to automatically trigger an export action when I save a file in Illustrator?

Tags: version-control, automation, export, applescript, adobe-illustrator

thanks for reading this question:

I have been working on a icon project with a few other designers. We are experimenting Github with version control, and we wanted to use the Image View mode to diff our icons.

However, since we are working in Illustrator, which is not supported by image mode, we cannot directly compare versions of icons. That is why we would like illustrator (or automator, applescript) to trigger an auto export option when the file is edited/saved, so we can compared the exported version (in PNG or JPG) with Image View mode on Github.

I hope that gives you an idea of our situation. Any answer would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't correlate to version-contol... have to be re-tagged?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer per-se, just some observations. Feel free to convert into comment

- I think, you selected wrong VCS for managing binary-data. Git works badly (well: suboptimally, inefficient) with binaries
- I think, you selected wrong workflow (compare non-original images on "server"-side), when you have local tool(s) **specifically designed** for such tasks (I kike update+diff better). You have only configure special differ for *ai file-type
- In any case, export before commit is not so frequent and complex task to have needs to automate this process